# Keras flow_from_directory function returns 'No such file or directory'

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I am making my first neural network,
It turns out that I have the following directories on my desktop:

[image: directory structure]

And within each class I have a large number of images with a JPG extension.

The problem is that when executing the 'flow_from_directory' function, I don't know how to pass the 'directory' parameter to the function since it always returns that it cannot find the directory.

[image: Directory error]

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: The screenshot looks like Windows, while the path you provided is for MacOS, no wonder it does not work.

Comment: I have also copied the file explorer path directly and it didn't work either.

Comment: Are you running this in Colab?

Comment: Yes, i am running this in Google Colab

Comment: Are you aware that code in Colab runs in a remote server, and not in your local computer? Local paths do not work on Colab for that reason.